SwiftUI: Items not marking as read when attempting to navigate past last page
I have a SwiftUI app that loads paginated data from Firestore. When users navigate between pages using a "Next" button, items are automatically marked as read. However, when users are on the last page and attempt to navigate further (even though there are no more items), the current items don't get marked as read.
Here's my current loadNextPage function in my FirestoreDataViewModel:
func loadNextPage() {
    guard let lastDocument = lastDocument, canLoadMore else {
        return
    }
    
    markUnreadItemsAsRead()
    isLoading = true
    currentPage += 1
    
    var query = db.collection("items")
        .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
        .start(afterDocument: lastDocument)
        
    // Apply filters
    if showFilterA {
        query = query.whereField("filterA", isEqualTo: true)
    }
    // ... other filters
    
    query.limit(to: itemsPerPage).getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        self.isLoading = false
        if let error = error {
            self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
            return
        }
        
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
            self.errorMessage = "No more data available"
            return
        }
        
        let newItems = snapshot.documents.compactMap { self.documentToItem($0) }
        self.items = newItems
        self.lastDocument = snapshot.documents.last
        self.canLoadMore = snapshot.documents.count == self.itemsPerPage
    }
}

What I've Tried

Moving markUnreadItemsAsRead() before the guard statement:

func loadNextPage() {
    markUnreadItemsAsRead()
    guard let lastDocument = lastDocument, canLoadMore else {
        return
    }
    // ... rest of the function
}


Directly updating Firestore in the guard statement:

func loadNextPage() {
    guard let lastDocument = lastDocument, canLoadMore else {
        let unreadItems = items.filter { !$0.read }
        for item in unreadItems {
            db.collection("items").document(item.id).updateData(["read": true])
        }
        return
    }
    // ... rest of the function
}


Using a separate function for marking items as read:

func markUnreadItemsAsRead() {
    let unreadItems = items.filter { $0.read == false }
    for item in unreadItems {
        db.collection("items").document(item.id).updateData(["read": true]) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error marking item as read: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let index = self.items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) {
                        self.items[index].read = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

None of these approaches successfully mark items as read when attempting to navigate past the last page.
Expected Behavior
When a user is on the last page and taps the "Next" button, even though there are no more items to load, the current items should be marked as read in both Firestore and the local state.
Question
How can I modify my code to ensure items are marked as read when attempting to navigate past the last page? I need a solution that:

Works with the existing pagination system
Updates both Firestore and local state
Handles the last page case correctly


In your guard let lastDocument = lastDocument, canLoadMore else { return }, I would think that canLoadMore is always false for the last page.

Where did you call loadNextPage function?

swift
self.canLoadMore = snapshot.documents.count == self.itemsPerPage
In the loadNextPage() method, canLoadMore is dynamically set based on the number of documents retrieved:
If the number of documents matches itemsPerPage (5 in this case), canLoadMore remains true
If fewer documents are retrieved than itemsPerPage, canLoadMore becomes false
Example Scenarios:
If 5 documents are retrieved: canLoadMore stays true
If 4 or fewer documents are retrieved: canLoadMore becomes false

Heres how loadNextPage is called:
Button(action: { viewModel.loadNextPage() }) {
Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
.foregroundColor(.blue)
}
.disabled(!viewModel.canLoadMore)

I might misunderstood, but I think you are marking the page as read once the user moves to the next item/page. Maybe you should mark them as read when they are presented

Thanks for your help! But when I mark them read when presented they will immediately be filtered out by my filter rules. And when I go to the detailview of an article in my reader and move back I cannot see the current list anymore as they are already unread. So I must find a way to mark all as read by pushing next on the last results. I am quite desperate. Any other ideas to fix this??

I could mark the all as read with a separate button. But I still cannot make them mark as read by pushing the next button on the last page:
